# UCB1 for Multiarmed bandits: understanding the proof

Tags: st.statistics, inequalities, machine-learning

Regarding Multiarmed Bandits, I am analysing algorithm UCB1 presented in [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1013689704352) paper and specifically the proof of Theorem 1, concerning the regret of the algorithm. At page 243 there is a step I do not understand:

$ \lceil \frac{8ln(n)}{\Delta_i^2} \rceil + \sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{s=1}^{t} \sum\limits_{s_i=1}^{t} 2t^{-4} \leq \frac{8ln(n)}{\Delta_i^2} +  1 + \frac{\pi^2}{3}$

My problem is that I do not get why you can move from $t$ to $\pi$. I guessed it might be really stupid, but I don't know how it works.

Also, in the same paper it is chosen $c_{t,s}=\sqrt{(2\ln(t))/s}$. Could someone explain me why it is, please? I thought they used Hoeffding inequality to get the confidence interval, but it is not that. I guessed they used a theorem concerning $\sigma$-subgaussian random variables, but I do not know the reference for this theorem. I am confused.

Could someone help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The sum is a complicated way of writing $\sum_{=1}^\infty 1/t^2 = \pi^2/6$

Comment: Thank you very much!